# Element not inserting correctly in HTML code

Tags: html

I have an issue that I never seen before. It is basic HTML though, I can't wrap my head around why it doesn't work.

Here is the code in my editor:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Prénom</td>
            <td>Nom</td>
            <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <!-- $allUsers is an array with a length of 13 -->
    <?php foreach($allUsers as $user):?>
        <tr>
            <td class="id-row"><?= $user['id']; ?></td>
            <div class="infos">
                <td class="fn-row"><?= $user['firstname']; ?></td>
                <td class="ln-row"><?= $user['lastname']; ?></td>
                <td class="mail-row"><?= $auser['email']; ?></td>
            </div>
            <td class="link-row"><a href="lireUser?id=<?= $user['id']?>">Lire</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is what comes out in the final page:
As expected, there are 13 occurences of the `.infos` div

[image]

I really don't see why this happens... The `<div>` should encapsulate the three `<tr>` but, as seen in the picture, they all get generated empty at the start, before the table

Comment: In HTML a **only** `<td>` and `<th>` elements are allowed as direct children of `<tr>` elements. Not divs. Since it's invalid to have a div there it's placed in the closest valid spot

Comment: Is there a way to put ```<tr>```s in a group as if they were inside of a ```<div>``` ?

Comment: I just don't think you can use div in this way. Browser will parse it in his own way to avoid the error

Comment: There is the `<colgroup>` element to group columns. However, it must be placed above the table and not inside a row.